# async / await with event-based function

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js

What is the use of async/await with a function that read and parse a file through an event-based processing ?
I saw this:

```
// readFile.js
function readFile(input) {
    csv.parseFile(input)
    .on('data', data => { ... })
    .on('end', ()=> { ... })
    .....
}
```

and from the test file there is:

```
// readFile.test.js
let file;
beforeEach(async () => {
    file = rewire('./readFile');
});

it('Testing...', async function () {
    await file.readFile(input);
    .....
})
```

What is the use of async/await in this test file ? I mean what is the await waiting for ?

Thank you

Comment: I’m guessing you are omitting important code. What does `readFile` return? I’m guessing it returns a promise that resolves on the `end` event among other things

Comment: Can you provide a complete code?